# Searching for database for Colorado soils that goes back to 1990's

Tags: database, soils

Are there any database for the soils database out there beside NRCS ? I am fully aware that NRCS has their database on their website but I was wondering if there is one that can't i find them ? I am looking more specific for Colorado. They can be either database or geospatial but I prefer them to be the database that goes back to 1990's They need to have mapunit, map name, and their survey areas ?

Answer (score 1):

The [ISRIC (International Soil Reference and Information Centre) Soil Data Hub](https://www.isric.org/explore/isric-soil-data-hub) has world-wide soil data from multiple sources.

You can search by data extent. It returned 102 search results for a rectangle drawn around Colorado. Results include a variety of information types such as carbon content, silt content, "harmonized world soil database" and many more.

https://data.isric.org/geonetwork/srv/eng/catalog.search#/search?resultType=details&sortBy=relevance&fast=index&_content_type=json&from=1&to=20&geometry=POLYGON((-109.45803386386183%2041.348463848972756,-109.45803386386183%2036.5322604625233,-101.59182292636184%2036.5322604625233,-101.59182292636184%2041.348463848972756,-109.45803386386183%2041.348463848972756))

Datasets on this website are licensed under Creative Commons licenses CC BY-NC or CC BY.